# How to restrict the values of an xsd element from another enumeration?

Tags: xml, xsd

Lets say i have the enumeration:

```
<xs:simpleType name="wheelerType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="2-wheeler"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="4-wheeler"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

now i am defining two more elements like below.

```
<xs:element name="Bike" type="wheelerType"/>
<xs:element name="Car" type="wheelerType"/>
```

Now how do i restrict Bike to be only 2-wheeler and Car to be only 4-wheeler?

Answer (score 0):

XML Schema allows to further restrict types with a similar construct: The `Bike` and `Car` elements can be associated with anonymous simple types that refine the enumeration introduced in `wheelerType` to only 2-wheeler or 4-wheeler.

```
<xs:element name="Bike">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="wheelerType">
            <xs:enumeration value="2-wheeler"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Car">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="wheelerType">
            <xs:enumeration value="2-wheeler"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: But in this case we will have 2 enums in the generated sources each with single value?

Comment: When you talk about "generated sources" (which I always feel is a contradiction in terms) this presumably means you are using some tool perhaps a data binding tool to generate something from your schema. You need to tell us what tool that is.